# Test of equality using if statement in C++

Tags: c++

This might be a stupid question to a experience programmer... but anyway, I just want to figure out. What's the difference between **if("Hello"==$helloString)** and **if(helloString=="Hello")**? I thought the order in a if statement doesn't matter but I guess there must be something wrong with my thought. So could someone expalin it to me? Like in what kind of situation would one use the first/second if statement to do the test of equality? Thanks!!

Comment: **Why** do you think there must be something wrong with your thoughts? If you're facing a real problem, why not just ask it instead of a theoretical one? Is that dollar sign suppose to be there?

Comment: And the comparison statement might change depending on helloString's data type. What is it, by the way?

Comment: Equality (==) is commutative, i.e. A == B implies B == A and vice versa. (Unless of course some crazy operator==() overloading.)

Comment: As a matter of style, some programmers put constants on the left side of comparisons to catch accidental assignment.

Comment: @Martin: Of course, that's silly. :)

Answer (score 7):

It's a "safety" measure.  If you have a typo, and leave out one of the '=' characters, you are doing assignment instead of comparison.

```
if (some_string = "Hello")
```

overwrites the string and the `if` is considered true (assuming using `std::string`).  On the other hand:

```
if ("Hello" = somestring)
```

is a compilation error.

It looks a little weird, but it's considered a good, preventative coding measure in some circles.

Comment: The term for this is "Yoda conditionals." :)

Comment: I like the "Yoda conditionals" moniker.  And while it is ugly, I cannot deny its effectiveness in catching the dreaded missing-one-character bug.

Comment: but there are other (better) ways to catch those bugs, for example compiler warnings. OK, so not all compilers warn for it, but you only need *one* of your compilers to emit a warning, since it's a fully platform-independent bug.

Comment: A `std::string` (like other reasonable string classes, I'd imagine) is not convertible to bool. Here this precaution serves no purpose other than to be consistent with the general style.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with your thought? I'll assume the random `$` symbol is a typo. Both lines check if an object `helloString` is actually equal to the literal string `"Hello"`. The ordering is a style preference - historically the constant was placed on the left hand side of the `==` to prevent accidental assignment (via `=`), though compilers now should warn of this behavior.

Do note that this would only work for objects of a type like `std::string`, which have overloaded `==` operators and would allow comparison such as this. This would not work if you were using C-style strings of `char *`.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string helloString = "Hello";
    char *helloPtr = "Hello";

    if (helloString == "Hello") { std::cout << "Equal 1\n"; }
    if ("Hello" == helloString) { std::cout << "Equal 2\n"; }
    if (helloPtr == "Hello") // not a *wise* comparison because you are comparing pointers
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Comparison of `char*` is LEGAL, but unlikely to have the desired effect.  It will tell you if both sides point to the same copy of "Hello", not whether the pointed-to strings compare equal.

Comment: Thanks both, it is 'legal' but wouldn't produce equality of strings as you say. If you do it with a literal the compiler would probably complain about the conversion of a literal to `char*`

Answer (score 1):

as [Tom mention](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993017/test-of-equality-using-if-statement-in-c/3993025#3993025)s, You should be using `strcmp` or `strncmp` with strings.  In other cases, some coding styles recommend putting the literal before the variable to avoid a common but sometimes difficult bug:

```
if (foo = 5)
{
    ...
}
```

The coder maybe meant `foo == 5`, which is true only if foo is equal to five, but instead has instructed the compiler to assign foo to five and do the if body every time.  by following that *literals first* rule, the coder would have written:

```
if (5 = foo)
{
    ...
}
```

which is invalid, and won't compile, because 5 is not an l-value.  The coder would have caught his mistake right away.

On the other hand, assignment in an if or while condition is actually a common idiom, and many C coders object to the *literals first* style because it's a little harder to read, for the same reason "If Angus is a Scotsman" scans more nicely than "If a Scotsman is Angus", even though both are technically equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Some compilers allow identifiers with $ symbols as a non-Standard extension... no big deal.

There are two aspects to this question - which you're interested in is not clear from the question:

- the functionality is equivalent, in which case the choice of which to use is stylistic, and the less-oft-seen `if("Hello" == helloString)` is prefered by some programmers as it produces a compiler error if `=` is accidentally typed instead of `==`
- you're observing (or wondering if there's any chance of) functionality differing: the rest of this answer addresses this.

For operator==, users can provide their own comparison operators for classes/structs they define:

```
struct X
{
    // as a member function
    bool operator==(const char* rhs) const { return <some expression>; }
};

// as a non-member function (use this OR the member function)
bool operator==(const X& lhs, const char* rhs) { return <some expression>; }

// only possible as a non-member function, as X doesn't appear on the left of ==
bool operator==(const char* lhs, const X& rhs) { return <some expression>; }
```

You can also define equality between two Xs as a member of non-member function...

```
struct X
{
    bool operator(const X& rhs) const { return <some expression>; }
};

OR

bool operator==(const X& lhs, const X& rhs) { return <some expression>; }
```

But, these functions would only allow comparison against a string literal (your "Hello" is a string literal), if you tell the compiler it is allowed to implicitly create an X from a string literal by means of a suitable constructor:

```
struct X
{
    X(const char* p) /* initialiser list eg. */ : p_(p) { <option code> }
};
```

This would allow `("Hello"==helloString)`, if helloString is our X type, to be resolved as:

```
(X("Hello") == helloString)
```

Which - as above - you provide as member `X::operator==(const X&)` or non-member `operator==(const X&, const X&)`.

Changing the constructor to be `explicit` prevents the compiler implicitly performing on-the-fly construction of Xs, which is typically best as implicit conversion can happen when not intended, and give make the intended resolution ambiguous or provide unwanted results.

```
struct X
{
    explicit X(const char* p) /* initialiser list eg. */ : p_(p) { <option code> }
};
```

Another way this expression can be evaluated for a user-defined type (class/struct), is to permit the compiler to create a type it already knows how to compare with a string literal from the user-defined type.  The compiler knows how to compare two string literals *but it doesn't do it in the way beginners expect* - instead it compares the memory addresses at which the text is stored rather than the textual content stored at those addresses.  This isn't normally useful to a beginner.  For the record, a conversion operator looks like this:

```
struct X
{
    operator const char*() const { return <some expression>; }
};
```

This would be even less desirable than non-explicit constructors - they have the same issues re making some intended matches ambiguous, but can also provide the less useful string address comparison instead of string content comparison.  Note that the C++ Standard's std::string provides a c_str() function that you must explicitly call when you want the address of the string content, and such an addresses may become invalid after any modification to the string (e.g. appending some more text).

Finally, if someString is NOT a class/struct, but is another string literal, then - as mentioned - the compiler will compare the addresses and not the string content.  You can use the strcmp() function to compare the textual content:

```
if (strcmp("Hello", someString)) // compare textual content
    ...
```

This works if the string content doesn't embed any NUL (0) characters.  Otherwise, a string class may provide a constructor from a pointer and data length (as std::string does), allowing:

```
if (X("Goodbye\000Cruel\000World", 19) == someString))
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no **$** operator in C++, therefore this statement is not valid:

```
if("Hello"==$helloString)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order does not matter. However, you should only use the == operator if helloString is a std::string and not a C string. Additionally, there is no $ operator in C++, so you should omit that.

For example, if helloString is a C string (e.g. char *) use the strcmp function:

```
if(strcmp("Hello", other_str) == 0) {
   //  they are equal
} else {
   // they are not equal
}
```

Or if helloString is a std::string, it is acceptable to use the == operator:

```
if("Hello" == helloString) {
   //  they are equal
} else {
   // they are not equal
}
```

EDIT: I made numerous edits due to comments. Thanks y'all.

Comment: Unless `other_str` is a `std::string`.

Comment: Yes provided you do `other_str.c_str()` if it was `std::string`

Comment: @birryree: that can produce inconsistent results, because `string` can contain embedded NUL bytes, whereas C-style strings are NUL-terminated. `char data[] = {'h', 'i', 0, 'x'}; std::string d(data,4);`. Now, `strcmp("hi", d.c_str())` is 0 (meaning "equal"), but `d == "hi"` is false (because it compares them as `std::string`, not as C-style strings). Going back to GMan's example, if `other_string` is a `std::string`, first you need to decide whether you should be comparing them as std::strings, or as NTBSs. Then use `operator==` or `strcmp` respectively.

Comment: @Steve: interesting, never knew that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If one or the other is not defined.  In the case of std::string, this is not the case.  But it's possible to define a function like this:

```
bool operator==(X lhs, Y rhs);
```

Then you can call that function like this:

```
X x;
Y y;
if(x == y) {...}
```

But you can't do this:

```
if(y == x) {...}
```

Unless you define another function like this:

```
bool operator==(Y lhs, X rhs);
```